# Or in assignment

Tags: python

I'm looking over someone else's code trying to learn from them and I have a question on something they've done.

This is line 16 from the link

```
self.sentence = sentence or ""
```

What does or in the assignment operator do?

I've tried running this myself and if sentence is defined then the it's assigned to self.sentence, otherwise if it's not assigned I get a NameError exception.

https://github.com/xavier/exercism-assignments/blob/master/python/bob/bob.py

Comment: If `sentence` evaluates to `false`, it assigns `""` to `self.sentence`. Otherwise (if `sentence` is a valid sentence presumably), then it assigns `self.sentence` to `sentence`.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ: that seems more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: Section 5.2 of https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html explains what "a or b" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`or` is a lazy operator, and returns first value, which is 'trueish' (`bool(value) is True`). This idiom is used, to assign a value, or if it is empty, something else.

In this case, probably it guards against assigning `None`, which evaluates to `False`, but author wanted to be sure, that be always a `string` will be assigned  - and empty string in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In the sample code, this would make more sense if `__init__()` had a default argument:

```
class Fake:
    def __init__(self, sentence=None):
        self.sentence = sentence or '<empty>'

    def print_me(self):
        print(self.sentence)

a = Fake('A real sentence')
b = Fake()

a.print_me()
b.print_me()
```

outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ ./def.py
A real sentence
<empty>
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$
```

In this particular case, `def __init__(self, sentence='<empty>'):` followed by `self.sentence = sentence` would have done equally well, but this could be more useful when dealing with mutable objects such as lists, since `def __init__(self, sentence=[]):` will evaluate only once, and all the classes would refer to the *same* default list. Specifying `None` as the default value instead, and creating a separate empty list in `__init__()` would avoid this behavior.

For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Weird:
    def __init__(self, the_list=[]):    # <--- Don't do this
        self.the_list = the_list

    def append(self, value):
        self.the_list.append(value)

    def print_me(self):
        print(self.the_list)

class Normal:
    def __init__(self, the_list=None):
        self.the_list = the_list or []

    def append(self, value):
        self.the_list.append(value)

    def print_me(self):
        print(self.the_list)

print("Weird output:")
a = Weird()
b = Weird()
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
a.print_me()
b.print_me()

print("Normal output:")
c = Normal()
d = Normal()
c.append(1)
c.append(2)
c.print_me()
d.print_me()
```

outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ ./def2.py
Weird output:
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
Normal output:
[1, 2]
[]
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$
```

In the first case, you might expect each object to get its own empty list, but you can see when you append things to `a`, they get appended to `b` also, because `a` and `b` are sharing the same list. This is not happening in the second case, because we specified the default as `None` rather than `[]`, and then used the idiom in your question. When `the_list` is `None`, `the_list or []` will evaluate to `[]`. When it's not, it'll just evaluate to `the_list`. It's equivalent to:

```
if sentence:
    self.sentence = sentence
else:
    self.sentence = ""
```